# How can i debug a program running in the kernel loaded by qemu-system-x86_64

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I compiled the Linux kernel and add a syscall.
The i run the kernel by qemu.
I have known using `target renote localhost:1234` to debug the kernel.

What's more, i wrote a program to test the syscall and want to debug it.
I compiled it using '-static', but ever can't break at the correct address.

I have searched on Google, but just know how to debug LKM(which located in the ring 0).

Then i attempt use '-no-pie' to compile the program, but also can't break at correct address. I guess it because of virtual memory or KPTI.

So, i want to know how to debug such program.

Comment: Now i use `b __x64_sys_syscallname` break  at the syscall. However, i still want to know if i can debug a user mode program

Comment: Could you not run gdbserver on top of the kernel that is running within QEMU, and run your test program within that gdbserver.  In your GDB session, add a second inferior, and connect that inferior to the second gdbserver.  You'll then have a single GDB session with two inferiors, the first inferior is the kernel, and the second will be the native Linux application.